# que solo un checkbox sea seleccionado en mi view

Tags: javascript, asp.net

quiero **checkbox** no **Radiobutton** los dos id sirven para mostrar y ocultar `DIV` y los `value` me envían valor al controlador

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-5">
        <input type="checkbox" name="tipoGrado"  id="checkGrado" value="1" onchange="javascript:showContentGrado()">Saldos por Grado
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-5">
        <input type="checkbox" name="tipoResumen"  id="checkResumen" value="2" onchange="javascript:showContentResumen()"> Resumen de Saldos
    </div>
</div>
```

conoces algun metodo javascript?

Answer (score 6):

Creo que algo como esto te puede ayudar, es algo parecido a la respuesta de kiramishima, solo que yo uso JS puro y utilizó las clases no los "names" de los checkboxs.

```js
let Checked = null;
//The class name can vary
for (let CheckBox of document.getElementsByClassName('only-one')){
 CheckBox.onclick = function(){
   if(Checked!=null){
      Checked.checked = false;
      Checked = CheckBox;
    }
    Checked = CheckBox;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-5">
        <input type="checkbox" name="tipoGrado"  id="checkGrado" value="1"  class="only-one">Saldos por Grado
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-5">
        <input type="checkbox" name="tipoResumen"  id="checkResumen" value="2"  class="only-one"> Resumen de Saldos
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: ¿Podrías explicarlo?

Answer (score 5):

se me ocurre algo con jquery, como esto :

```
$("input:checkbox").on('click', function() {
  // in the handler, 'this' refers to the box clicked on
  var $box = $(this);
  if ($box.is(":checked")) {
    var group = "input:checkbox[name='" + $box.attr("name") + "']";
    $(group).prop("checked", false);
    $box.prop("checked", true);
  } else {
    $box.prop("checked", false);
  }
});
```

y en el HTML modificaria:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-5">
        <input type="checkbox" name=type  id="checkGrado" value="1" onchange="javascript:showContentGrado()">Saldos por Grado
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-5">
        <input type="checkbox" name="type"  id="checkResumen" value="2" onchange="javascript:showContentResumen()"> Resumen de Saldos
    </div>
</div>
```

Con eso ya solo podrias seleccionar uno del mismo grupo que tengan el mismo name, saludos

Fidle: https://jsfiddle.net/2qudL12L/

Answer (score 2):

este codigo tambien es puro javascript:

```js
function uncheck(){
    var checkbox1 = document.getElementById("vehiculo");
    var checkbox2 = document.getElementById("moto");
    checkbox1.onclick = function(){
    if(checkbox1.checked != false){
       checkbox2.checked =null;
    }
}
checkbox2.onclick = function(){
    if(checkbox2.checked != false){
        checkbox1.checked=null;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="vehiculo" onclick="uncheck()" name="vehiculo"> Vehículo Liviano<br>
<input type="checkbox" id="moto" onclick="uncheck()" name="moto"> Motocicleta<br>
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
    function uncheck(){
     var checkbox1 = document.getElementById("vehiculo");
     var checkbox2 = document.getElementById("moto"); 
    checkbox1.onclick = function(){ 
    if(checkbox1.checked != false){ 
    checkbox2.checked =null; }
     } 
    checkbox2.onclick = function(){ 
    if(checkbox2.checked != false){ 
    checkbox1.checked=null;
     }
     } 
    }
```

```html
    <input type="checkbox" id="vehiculo" onclick="uncheck()" name="vehiculo"> Vehículo Liviano<br>
    <input type="checkbox" id="moto" onclick="uncheck()" name="moto"> Motocicleta<br>
```

Comment: linuxero, bienvenido a SOes. Te recomiendo que puedas hacer el [tour]. Tenemos un excelente editor de codigo en nuestra pagina de respuestas. Considera [edit] tu respuesta y mostrar al OP como funcionaria tu codigo en la realidad, de igual forma que las otras respuestas lo han hecho.

Comment: de paso te recomiendo  también no publicar múltiples respuestas en la misma publicación; no es bien visto y no es necesario, deja una de las 2 dale editar y mejora su contenido

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow. He editado tu respuesta para darle el formato de código apropiado. TE invito a pulsar el botón de editar y ver como debe quedar. Por otro lado, las respuestas con solo código, sin explicación, tienden a ser consideradas de baja calidad por la comunidad. Te recomiendo añadir una explicación de lo que has recomendado. Un saludo.